# How can one sort a column of text based on a different column of numerical values?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet where a couple of colleagues and I are rank-ordering some books based on our preferences. It looks something like this:

```
Books,John Ranks,Smith Ranks,Doe Ranks
book1,1,3,2
book2,3,1,1
book3,2,2,3
```

In this ranking world, the highest rank for a book is `1`, and the lowest rank is `{number of books}`, which would be `3` in this example. I have a column, `Totals`, that counts the rank of something:

```
Books,John Ranks,Smith Ranks,Doe Ranks,Totals
book1,1,3,2,6
book2,3,1,1,5
book3,2,2,3,7
```

In this example, `book2` would have won out, because it has the lowest number and therefore has the highest preference. Now, I want to have another column, `True Ranks` or something, that sorts the names of the books based on the values in the `Totals` column. A `total` cell value will always be in the same row as the book it represents. I want to write a function for `True Ranks` that will have in rank-order (sorted order) the book names based on the total values in ascending order. So, it would look something like this:

```
Books,John Ranks,Smith Ranks,Doe Ranks,Totals,True Ranks
book1,1,3,2,6,book2
book2,3,1,1,5,book1
book3,2,2,3,7,book3
```

Because `{book2: 5, book1: 6, book3: 7}` is the ascending order. Scratching my head on how this would happen in a spreadsheet, I'm not well-versed in all the options available. Any ideas?

Edit: I am not sure if I am explaining this well enough (there is always the fear of this happening): in programmatic terms, I essentially have two lists, one int list `Totals` and one String list `Books`, and I am asking how I could ***first*** copy the String list (I do not want to modify the String list) ***and*** the int list (I also don't want to modify the int list), then sort them both simultaneously (though I suppose the result of the int list sort won't be displayed anywhere).

...Any ideas?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `SORT` function in a formula

```
=SORT(A2:A4,E2:E4,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
F1=sort(A1:E3,5,False)
```

Sort is an array function so needs clearance below and to the right it for the results.

This will return all 5 columns.  You can hide the unwanted ones.

You can also be clever (which will bite you later...) and construct a range on the fly:

```
 F1=sort({A1:A3,E1:E3},2,False)
```

This eliminates the extra columns of individual results.

Answer (score 0):

try direct approach:

```
=QUERY(SORT({A2:A, B2:B+C2:C+D2:D}, 2, 1),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", )
```

[image]